# PostgreSQL slower query after partitioning

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-9.5

I have a 75GB table with more than 100M records.
I've **partitioned that table by month**. Each partition is ~8M records big.

Most of the queries works on recent data and almost every query filters by the timestamp field used for partitioning. Also, monthly, old (more than 2 years) data is deleted. So it seemed to me that partitioning could help both query performance and old data deletion.

I followed this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html to partition the tables (the case there is very similar to mine)

Every child table has a CHECK constraint

```
CONSTRAINT p_inbox_201702_datarilev_check 
    CHECK (datarilev >= '2017-02-01'::date 
       AND datarilev < '2017-03-01'::date)
```

and an index on the timestamp field (`datarilev`).

I've also dropped all the indexes from the parent table (it doesn't seem to make any difference).

Now, **if I query the parent table** using a date range :

```
select id 
from p_inbox 
where datarilev > '2017-02-02'::date 
  and datarilev < '2017-02-03'::date 
limit 10;
```

it takes ~ 10 seconds.

If I query a single partition

```
select id 
from p_inbox_201702 
where datarilev > '2017-02-02'::date 
  and datarilev < '2017-02-03'::date 
limit 10
```

it takes 50 milliseconds.

If I query the non-partitioned table

```
select id 
from p_inbox_full 
where datarilev between '2017-02-02' and '2017-02-03'
```

it takes 200 milliseconds.

These are the results from an explain analyze of the three queries:

Query the parent: https://explain.depesz.com/s/EOoW

Query the partition: https://explain.depesz.com/s/MMnT

Query the full, non-partitioned table: https://explain.depesz.com/s/Bk4Z

It seems that the partitions are excluded correctly: disabling constraint_exclusion, the plan changes accordingly.

So, my question is: is it normal that **checking the constraints** to exclude out of range tables **takes 10 seconds**?

Version is PostgreSQL 9.5.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

Comment: How many partitions do you have? Postgres is known to be not very efficient if you have several thousands of partitions. Can you try the same queries on 9.6? I think there were some improvements to the optimizer when dealing with many partitions

Comment: On the parent, have you tried `where datarilev between '2017-02-02 00:00:00' and '2017-02-03 00:00:00'`, or creating an index for each partition on `datarilev::DATE`?

Comment: At the moment, there are 19 partitions. There will never be more than 25 (two years + the month to be deleted) partitions.

Comment: Thank you bma, I just tried to change all the check constraints to '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, the query argument to '2017-02-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone, so that query, indexes, constraints and table use the same data type: no luck, it continues to take ~10 seconds.

Comment: And the query plan still performed proper constraint exclusion? If not, try with both the date _and_ the timestamp filters against the parent.

Comment: A LIMIT without an ORDER BY is rarely a sensible thing to do.  Is that what you actually want, or is that the result of some attempted optimization?

Comment: Can you post an `explain (analyze, buffers)` of the parent query, preferably with track_io_timing turned on?  Something seems very wrong with your index `p_inbox_201702_darilev`.

Comment: For a 75 GB table I would have start with partial indexes with clustered table.

Comment: Tahnk you jjanes, the LIMIT is there just to avoid getting back too much results. Removing the LIMIT does not affect query plan/performance (apart from the LIMIT row of the plan, of course).

Comment: jjanes, here's the result of an explain (analyze, buffers) with track_io_timing=on https://explain.depesz.com/s/8Fj

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Sahap Asci, I wasn't aware of those features. I think partial indexes can help query performance in my case. However, I can't understand how to use both partial indexes and clustered table. Are you suggesting to cluster by a "full" index and to also define a partial index for each month?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, thank you, it seems to work fine with 9.6!

Comment: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/performance-testing-between-partitioned-and-non-partitioned-postgresql-tables-part-3/comment-page-1/#comment-316695 implies it "can sometimes be faster" also feel free to post an "answer" to your own question here if you figured something out, thanks!

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417922/2979435)